# Cisco 2516 Console access via RJ45 port?

Tags: cisco, cable

I have just taken delivery of a basic Cisco lab and I would like to check the routers and switches etc. are in 'working' condition before I start playing around with them.

The first hurdle is probably the most obvious - I don't know how to get console access to actually do anything on the hardware!

The first in the list is a Cisco 2516 - you can see the ports available on the following table (taken from [this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps233/products_data_sheet09186a0080092047.html) website:

[image: Datasheet]

Here is a list of the contents of the lab (provided to show you what cables I have access to):

[image: lab contents]

I also have a serial to USB cable that I had before the lab arrived.

So far I have tried to connect to the RJ45 console port on the Cisco 2516, to the RJ45 port on my laptop. It would appear from everything I have read online that you have to connect to either serial or USB on the laptop - is this correct?

If so, do I need two adapters? One thats RJ45 to USB and another thats DCE/DTE to USB?

I notice that none of the equipment has the RS-232 serial connection that I expected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console port on the 2516 is indeed a serial port, but it uses an RJ45 connector and a weird "rollover cable" to connect the RJ45 console port on the hub to the serial port on your laptop.  You should have got a rollover cable with the hub; last time I bought any Cisco kit, they were light blue thin ribbon-style cables with a standard 9-pin serial connector on one end and an RJ45 connector on the other.  They're called rollover cables because the pins at either end are wired 1->8, 2->7, 3->6, etc.

[image]

Comment: @Chopper3: thanks for the edit!  I didn't realise you could just include the image like that.

Comment: Great thanks! The above cable went into the serial to USB and it all worked. Thanks again!

Comment: It's not the most intuitive connector scheme, is it?  Happy to help.

Comment: No, it's not! I can't help but ask why it's _still_ like that.

Comment: I've no idea; presumably it made sense to somebody at Cisco at some point.

Comment: Asking Cisco why they *still* do things in certain old ways would be a lifetime's work

Comment: Actually they don't still do that.  The latest routers from Cisco now have the old RJ45 console as well as a 5pin mini-USB console which works as a USB->Serial converter (Cisco provides a driver that keeps the port number assigned so the USB console always comes up as the same COM port for your terminal software to use).  So a standard mini-usb cable can be your console cable on those routers.

Comment: This type of cable makes a lot of sense in Data Centres with structured cabling as you can use the existing RJ45 patch panels to carry the console data and have a central console server such as an Avocent Cycades.

Answer (score 0):

Each piece of equipment equipped with a console port should include a baby blue colored rollover cable. This flat cable should have a DB-9 on one end and a RJ-45 on the opposite end. The DB-9 should plug right into your USB-to-serial converter.